# R language, var matrix gives negative values

Tags: r, matrix, var, negative-number

So when using the R programming language, (which I'm very new to) I have a 4x2 matrix "gg" and when I do var(gg) it returns a 2x2 matrix as follows.

```
> gg <- matrix(c(4,2,4,5, 9, 14, 2, 32), nrow = 4, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
> gg
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    4    2
[2,]    4    5
[3,]    9   14
[4,]    2   32

> var(gg)
           [,1]   [,2]
[1,]   8.916667 -11.25
[2,] -11.250000 182.25
```

now I understand that the 8.916 and the 182.25 are the variances of the first and second columns.

But what is the -11.5 ?

I have read that it could be a computed covariance or correlation? But a covariance cant be negative and a correlation must be between -1 and 1 so -11.5 satisfies neither of those two conditions. So I really don't understand what this -11.5 is representing?

Comment: It should be the covariance between the first and second column i.e. `cov(gg[,1], gg[,2])
#[1] -11.25`.    Usually, the variance matrix has diagonals as the variance and offdiagonals as the covariance.

Comment: Compare to `cov(gg[,1], gg[,2]); sum((gg[,1]-mean(gg[,1]))* (gg[,2]-mean(gg[,2])))/(nrow(gg)-1)` Negative covariance means an inverse dependency (in the sense of a linear regression): greater values in `gg[,2]` imply lower values in `gg[,1]`

Comment: Yes your right, dont know what I was thinking saying covariance cant be negative, so if anyone want to write that up in an actual answer i will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

`var(gg)` where `gg` is a matrix of columns `x` and `y` returns:

```
cov(xx), cov(xy)
cov(yx), cov(yy)

cov(xy) = cov(yx) because cov is defined as
E((x - xbar)(y - ybar)) = E((y - ybar)(x - xbar))
```